# Web content is returned as undefined when I make a selection from a dynamically created selection list

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I'm still working on an assignment for a javscript/dhtml class. The assignment is to dynamically create a selection list and fill list with character names as the options. This I have completed. The second part of the assignment is to create a function to show the character name(H3 element) selected and the lines of the play(Blockquote element) said by the character.

The problem I'm having now is, when I make a selection, the values returned are 'undefined'. I feel like I am close to completing this project, just need a little extra help! I would love any help!

Here is a small clip of the HTML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- 
   New Perspectives on HTML, XHTML and DHTML 4th Edition
   Tutorial 16
   Case Problem 4

   The Tempest
   Author: Collin Klopstein
   Date: December 15, 2013  

   Filename:         tempest.htm
   Supporting files: bio_out.jpg, globe_out.jpg, plays.css, plays_out.jpg,
                     scene.js, son_out.jpg, strat_out.jpg
-->

<title>The Tempest, Act V, Scene 1</title>
<link href="plays.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="scene.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="linklist">
   <img src="plays_out.jpg"  alt="The Plays" />
   <img src="son_out.jpg"  alt="The Sonnets" />
   <img src="bio_out.jpg" alt="Biography" />
   <img src="globe_out.jpg" alt="The Globe" />
   <img src="strat_out.jpg" alt="Stratford" />
</div>
<div id="title"><img src="tempest.jpg" alt="The Tempest" /></div>
<div id="actList"><table><tr>
   <td>ACT I</td><td>ACT II</td><td>ACT III</td>
   <td>ACT IV</td><td>ACT V</td>
</tr></table></div>

<div id="characterList"></div>


<div id="sceneIntro">
<h2>Lines from Act V, Scene 1</h2>
</div>

<div id="scene">
<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote><i>Enter PROSPERO in his magic robes, and ARIEL</i></blockquote>
<blockquote>Now does my project gather to a head:<br />
My charms crack not; my spirits obey; and time<br />
Goes upright with his carriage. How's the day?
</blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote>On the sixth hour; at which time, my lord,<br />
You said our work should cease.
</blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote>I did say so,<br />
When first I raised the tempest. Say, my spirit,<br/>
How fares the king and's followers?
</blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote>Confined together<br />
In the same fashion as you gave in charge,<br />
Just as you left them; all prisoners, sir,<br />
In the line-grove which weather-fends your cell;<br />
They cannot budge till your release. The king,<br />
His brother and yours, abide all three distracted<br />
And the remainder mourning over them,<br />
Brimful of sorrow and dismay; but chiefly<br />
Him that you term'd, sir, 'The good old lord Gonzalo;<br />
His tears run down his beard, like winter's drops<br />
From eaves of reeds. Your charm so strongly works 'em<br />
That if you now beheld them, your affections<br />
Would become tender.
</blockquote>

<h3>PROSPERO</h3>
<blockquote>Dost thou think so, spirit?
</blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3>
<blockquote>Mine would, sir, were I human.
</blockquote>
```

and the JavaScript file:

```
/*
   New Perspectives on HTML, XHTML, and DHTML 4th Edition
   Tutorial 16
   Case Problem 4

   Author: Collin Klopstein  
   Date: December 15, 2013    

   Filename: scene.js


   Function List:
   uniqueElemText(elemName)
      Returns the unique content from HTML tags with the
      tag name elemName. The list is sorted in alphabetical
      ordered and returned as an array.

*/



function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
   if (object.attachEvent)
       object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
   else if (object.addEventListener)
       object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

addEvent(window, "load", characterBox, false);//calls createListBox() when page loads
var sourceDoc = document.getElementById("scene");
function uniqueElemText(elemName) {
   elems = document.getElementsByTagName(elemName);
   elemsArray = new Array();

   for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) elemsArray[i]=elems[i].innerHTML;  
   elemsArray.sort();
   for (i=0; i<elemsArray.length-1; i++) {
      if (elemsArray[i]==elemsArray[i+1]) {
         elemsArray.splice(i+1,1);
         i--;
      }
   }
   return elemsArray;
}

function characterBox(object, option) {
    var boxHead = document.getElementById("characterList");//references div with id characterList
    boxHead.innerHTML = "<p>Show Only Lines By:</p>";//adds <p> element to characterList div
    var cList = document.createElement("select");//creates <select> element
    boxHead.appendChild(cList);//appends <select> element to characterList div

    var characters = uniqueElemText("h3");//creates characters array that calls uniqueElemText() and applies all h3 elements

    var showAll = document.createElement("option");//creates option element
    showAll.text = "Show All Character Lines";// value of option element
    showAll.value = 'ALL';
    cList.add(showAll);//adds showAll as option of selection list

    for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        var options = document.createElement("option");
        options.innerHTML = characters[i];
        cList.appendChild(options);
        addEvent(cList, "change", sortLines, false);
    }
}



function sortLines(e) {
    var character = e.target.value || e.srcElement.value;
    var displayStatus = "";//stores display status to displayStatus var; value empty string, default status applied by browser
    var sourceDoc = document.getElementById("scene");
    for (var n = sourceDoc.firstChild; n != null; n = n.nextSibling) {
        var nodeName = document.createElement("h3");
        nodeName.innerHTML = sourceDoc[n];
        var quote = document.createElement("blockquote");
        quote.innerHTML = sourceDoc[n];
        nodeName.appendChild(quote);

        if (nodeName.innerHTML.indexOf("<h3>" + character + "</h3>") != -1) {
            displayStatus = "none";
        }
        else
            displayStatus = nodeName.innerHTML;
    }
    sourceDoc.innerHTML = displayStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER

This javascript code is working i have tested it

```
var hiddenElement = new Array();

function sortLines(e) {
    var character = e.target.value || e.srcElement.value;
    for ( var x = 0; x < hiddenElement.length; x++ ) {
        hiddenElement[x].style.display = 'block'; // display all hidden elements
    }
    if (character === 'ALL') { return false; } // return from here if all is selected
    var allheadingelm = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");
    var otherelm = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < allheadingelm.length; i++) {
        if (allheadingelm[i].innerHTML.indexOf(character) == -1) {
            otherelm.push(allheadingelm[i]);
        }
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < otherelm.length; j++) {

        for (var n = otherelm[j].nextElementSibling; n != null; n = n.nextElementSibling) {
            if (n.tagName.indexOf("H3") != -1  && n.innerHTML.indexOf(character) != -1) {
                break;
            } else {
                n.style.display = "none";
                hiddenElement.push(n);
            }   
        }

        otherelm[j].style.display = 'none'; 
        hiddenElement.push(otherelm[j]);

    }   
}
```

---

OLD ANSWER

If i have understood it correctly now you have character list containing PROSPERO and ARIEL as option, what you want is on select of any option it should get you the dialogues related to option selected. Efficient way is to add class to the dialogues/blockquotes say

```
<h3>PROSPERO</h3> <blockquote class="PROSPERO">Dost thou think so, spirit? </blockquote>

<h3>ARIEL</h3> <blockquote class="ARIEL">Mine would, sir, were I human. </blockquote>
```

so that it is easier for you to perform javascript selection using

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

Have created a fiddle with you requirement, please check. It will not be exact but logic will remain same http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/45UT5/

There is one more fiddle if you want all the styling also, first fiddle will just give you html

http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/45UT5/1/

Comment: Ok, the only issue I have with this is, I am not supposed to make any changes to the html file. It is all supposed to be completed through my Javascript file

Comment: I just added it for example purpose as to make javascript work was more important in your context. You can add element through javascript by using document.createElement

Comment: I apologize for not getting my point across. I am just trying to wrap my head around this. It is my first week working with dynamic html. I feel as though I am close with my above code. When I select a character it shows the word "undefined" for both the character and lines, in the correct format. Is there something I can do to my if/else or displayStatus?

Comment: Can you please provide the exact code where are you getting this. As it will be easy for me to analyze.

Comment: I know this probably isn't the preferred method, but I posted my JScript file as an answer. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me!

Comment: Wow, I was way off! I will definitely spend some time studying this. Now that I see it, it makes a little more sense. Thank you so much for the help! Obviously it was much needed.